# Create list and add a choices column to default view

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model

I would like to create a link list, and then add a choice column (Field) with two choices to the default view.

Using the following code i am able to create the list and add a column (Field) to the default view. I cant get the //CREATE FIELD part working:

```
// CREATE NEW LIST 
        ListCreationInformation newList12 = new ListCreationInformation();
        // Titel
        newList12.Title = "Links";
        newList12.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Links; // Template
        newList12.QuickLaunchOption = QuickLaunchOptions.Off; // Quicklaunch option
        List list12 = web.Lists.Add(newList12); 
        newList12.Description = "Opret og del links";
        // Update list + execute
        list12.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        //CREATE FIELD
        List listUpdate12 = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Links");
        listUpdate12.Fields.Add("Field Name", FieldType.Choice, false);

        //Get Field Reference
        FieldChoice col = (FieldChoice)listUpdate12.Fields.GetByTitle["Field Name"];

        col.Choices.Add("option 1");
        col.Choices.Add("option 2");
        col.DefaultValue = "option 1"; //otherwise blank row by default.

        col.update();  //Saves choices to column

        listUpdate12.Update();


        // ADD FIELD TO VIEW
        View view12 = list12.Views.GetByTitle("All Links");
        view12.ViewFields.Add("Field Name");

        // update view + list
        view12.Update();
        list12.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

When i hower the "listUpdate12.Fields.Add("Field Name", FieldType.Choice, false);" part i get: Error: No overload method "Add" takes 3 arguments.

When i hower the "listUpdate12.Fields.GetByTitle["Field Name"];" part i get: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

1. <strike>You'll want to use the SPFieldType class instead of FieldType.</strike>
   Update: Actually, the issue is that the CSOM doesn't support that version of Add. Use AddAsXml instead:

   `list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("",true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);`
2. When you call GetByTitle you're using [] - square brackets. Try using parenthesis to call the method instead - GetByTitle("Field Name")

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried using the SPFieldType. I get the error: The name 'SPFieldType' does not exist in the current context. ??

The parenthesis helped, thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice this was using the CSOM. What you'll want to do is use the AddFieldAsXml function instead of add:

list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field DisplayName='MyField2' Type='Choice' />", 
                                           true, 
                                           AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);

Comment: Thank you, thats much better, almost there! Only one problem left: The col.Choices.Add("option 1"); parts, doesnt work. When i hower .Add i get: 'System.Array' does not contain a definitions for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (Are you missing a using directive og an assembly?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Yep, so the reason that's happening is that FieldChoice.Choices is of the type string[] - arrays in C# have fixed length, so they don't support the Add method.  What you probably want to do instead is just re-initialize Choices like so:
col.Choices = new string[] { "option 1","option 2" };

Comment: Okay nice, seems to work! However it breaks at: FieldChoice col = (FieldChoice)listUpdate12.Fields.GetByTitle("Field Name"); 
With message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in CreateList.exe
Additional information: An object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field' can not be converted to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldChoice'.

Comment: I believe that you want to use the CastTo method of the ClientContext: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee541159(v=office.15).aspx

So:  FieldChoice col = context.CastTo<FieldChoice>(listUpdate12.Fields.GetByTitle("Field Name"));

Comment: Yep thats betters. Now it returns this error: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

The code creates the list, but it doesnt create ore add the field. Thanks in advance.